# call functions from a docker image based on a conda python project

Tags: python, docker, conda

I dont quite understand how to make a docker image and then run a basic function please
My toy project (running on a conda env) looks like one shown below, at the bottom:

The build looks to executed fine `docker build --no-cache -t my_docker_img .`   What I dont understand is how I can load the image and call the functions exposed by the package `print_hi, app` and pass some user-defined arguments to them please.

I am a real beginner with docker, this is literally my first one.

```
dockerize_me\
    |
    |
    |
    dockerize_me\
        |
        |
        __init__.py
        main.py
        utils.py
    |
    |
    dockerfile
    environment.yml
    setup.py
```

where the file contents are:

****init**.py**

```py
# file: __init__.py
from dockerize_me.main import print_hi, app
```

**main.py**

```py
from dockerize_me.utils import add_scalar
import numpy as np
    
    
def print_hi(name):
    print("hello %s" % name )  
    
    
def app(lst_in, const):
    arr = add_scalar(np.array(lst_in), const)
    return arr
```

**utils.py**

```py
def add_scalar(arr, scalar):
    return arr + scalar
```

**environment.yml**

```yaml
name: dockerize_me
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - pip
  - python=3.8
  - numpy
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM mambaorg/micromamba:0.19.1
    
ARG MAMBA_DOCKERFILE_ACTIVATE=1
COPY environment.yml .
RUN micromamba env create -f environment.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

After building the image you need to run the image as an container. Note that the container and image name are two different parameters, as you can start one image in multiple containers:

`docker run <image_name> <container_name>`

To just run your python functions once inside the container environment you could "step into" the container using the exec command, and run your python code using the shell like this:

```
docker exec -it <container_name> bash
python
from dockerize_me.main import print_hi
print_hi("Max")
```

Note:
if you are unsure about your availible images and running containers you can check them by using:

```
docker image ls
docker ps
```

instead of running the python code in the shell you could also run a python file which imports your functions.